# MacOS Ventura13.3 with Bundle Install eventmachine stuck in failing loop

Tags: ruby, rubygems, bundler, eventmachine

There have been multiple accounts similar to this, but something different is going on here. I wrote about this question [here](https://github.com/rubygems/rubygems/issues/6584).

Here is background information:

```
$  which ruby                                                                                                
/Users/johnlarkin/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.1.3/bin/ruby
$  ruby -v
ruby 3.1.3p185 (2022-11-24 revision 1a6b16756e) [arm64-darwin22]
$  which openssl
/opt/homebrew/opt/openssl@3/bin/openssl
$  openssl version                                                                                           
OpenSSL 3.1.0 14 Mar 2023 (Library: OpenSSL 3.1.0 14 Mar 2023)
```

I can install `eventmachine` like this:

```
$  gem install eventmachine -v '1.2.7' -- --with-ssl-dir=/opt/homebrew/opt/openssl@3
Building native extensions with: '--with-ssl-dir=/opt/homebrew/opt/openssl@3'
This could take a while...
Successfully installed eventmachine-1.2.7
Parsing documentation for eventmachine-1.2.7
Done installing documentation for eventmachine after 0 seconds
1 gem installed
```

However, when I go to `bundle install`, it still doesn't work:

```
                                                   ^
4 warnings generated.
linking shared-object rubyeventmachine.bundle
Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
  "_SSL_get1_peer_certificate", referenced from:
      SslBox_t::GetPeerCert() in ssl.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [rubyeventmachine.bundle] Error 1

make failed, exit code 2

Gem files will remain installed in
/Users/johnlarkin/Desktop/Coding_Learning/github_files/johnlarkin1.github.io/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/eventmachine-1.2.7
for inspection.
Results logged to
/Users/johnlarkin/Desktop/Coding_Learning/github_files/johnlarkin1.github.io/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/extensions/arm64-darwin-22/3.1.0/eventmachine-1.2.7/gem_make.out

An error occurred while installing eventmachine (1.2.7), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install eventmachine -v '1.2.7' --source 'https://rubygems.org/'` succeeds before bundling.

In Gemfile:
  jekyll-sleek was resolved to 0.1.9, which depends on
    jekyll-seo-tag was resolved to 2.8.0, which depends on
      jekyll was resolved to 3.9.2, which depends on
        em-websocket was resolved to 0.5.3, which depends on
          eventmachine
```

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: You may want to check if there's any lingering [bundle config](https://bundler.io/v1.12/man/bundle-config.1.html) settings that are impacting your `eventmachine` install, or you may want to set a `build.eventmachine` that matches what you did with the `--with-ssl-dir` option.

Comment: Oh my literally goodness @tadman -  you're a freaking genius. `$  bundle config build.eventmachine --with-ssl-dir=/opt/homebrew/opt/openssl@3
You are replacing the current global value of build.eventmachine, which is currently "--with-cppflags=-I/opt/homebrew/opt/openssl@3/include"`

Comment: Worth adding a self-answer if you can confirm this works, plus what you did to fix it. Glad to help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Huge thank you to @tadman for the helpful suggestion. The issue was with the `bundle config settings` ([link](https://bundler.io/v1.12/man/bundle-config.1.html))

It seems like due to an earlier incorrect command specification, something about the build process had become cached.

I ran:

```
$  bundle config build.eventmachine --with-ssl-dir=/opt/homebrew/opt/openssl@3 

You are replacing the current global value of build.eventmachine,
which is currently "--with-cppflags=-I/opt/homebrew/opt/openssl@3/include"
```

After doing this, `bundle install` proceeded to work totally normally. Thank you again @tadman!